# How should I start yarn server?

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, package.json, yarn-lock.json

PS C:\Users\Mahima\OneDrive\Desktop\StackOverflow-clone> yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.

I have installed all the required dependencies along with yarn still it is showing the error "warning package.json: No license field"

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is to add following to your `package.json` file

```
{
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Have 
private: true 
as well as 
license: "MIT"

and still get the error